# Web Server for Upload files

Tags: authentication, iis, ftp, active-directory, forms

I have a requirement where I want HTML FTP to be accessed by AD users. When users prompted to supply their AD credentials, the IIS/FTP should mapped them directly to their folders. What I want is, an HTML "Form" page/website when its accessed from internal/external it will prompt and users will supply AD credentials. Based on the permission set on the folders users will access only their folder and will upload to their folder only. The Upload as a Browse Button which will allow them to upload specified documents to their folder only. So, When they log into their computer at work they will be able to see what has been uploaded and will be able to open that document directly.

This is actually for Part Time Lectures, currently all the shared we have on a Windows 2008 R2 and permission set based on AD.

Is this doable via HTML or any other code or FTP itself. Even third party software which will be fine too.

Comment: You can use Drop Box / Google Drive with different credentials for each user.

Comment: I don't want to use public services.. ZFTP Server it does the job require, but can't customize the web Interface to put our branding..

Comment: @tarzanbappa, please don't add `code formatting` to words that you think are important.  It's for code, not emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth taking a look at plupload - depending on your usage, you might need to pay licensing: http://www.plupload.com